# Extracting a table which isn’t loading in full from the website using Power Query

Tags: excel, web-scraping, web, powerquery

I am trying to extract a table from a website using power query. Unfortunately the table does not load fully by default and I have to keep pressing Load More to get it to load the full table. But this doesn’t change the URL so the default table which only shows 20 rows gets loaded into Excel when I extract it using Power Query. How do I get it to extract the full hundred plus rows?

I went through the steps for extracting tables using Power Query - New Query - From Other Sources - From Web - Paste URL - then select the table from Navigator

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Power Query cannot handle these types of situation. You have two options:

1. Look at the page source HTML and JS to see where the data is being loaded from. Sometimes, it is possible to use Power Query to link directly to the API and bypass the web page.
2. Use an alternative tool to scrape the data. In the past, I have used Power Automate Desktop for situations like this. e.g.

[Web Scraping Made EASY With Power Automate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgBZiBIgh3w)